# Meteor: what are the best settings in a production environment?

Tags: meteor

I am developing a meteor application. I noticed that the meteor server sometimes suddently crashes, this makes me think that it might not be optimized for production.

In a production environment, should I consider to add/remove some packages? Which one? And what are the best settings? **I just want to make sure to have a reliable server that stay up all the time.**

Comment: Without any list of the packages installed, or the cause of the server error and subsequent codes, it will be hard to give a good answer if at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [meteor up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) yet? It will set up a production quality server for you. I've used it for several production applications and it works great.

As far as adding/removing packages goes, I've never ran into any problems with installed packages running on production. A couple of my apps have about a dozen or so packages installed. But if you suspect that a package might be causing the problem, I would go to atmosphere and search for your packages and make sure that they haven't been flagged. You'll see a bright red flag next to the package name if it's been flagged by the community as "not working".

Maybe also check for issues on GitHub.

If you do decide to use meteor up, after your app has been uploaded to the server, you can check the log s for any problems.

`mup logs -f`

Comment: Does mup "optimize" the server? I think it only transfer the files to the production server. In this case a simple bash script would do the same job...

Comment: What do you mean by optimize the server? I know that it sets up forever for you, so that if the server does crash, it will fire the server right back up. If you're using something like digital ocean to host your app, then all you really need to do is select a droplet size, and then use mup to set up the server for production. If the droplet is not big enough, and is getting bogged down, then you just simply increase the size. The same is true for something like ec2.

Comment: ok. So it's exactly what I am looking for! I need that kind of watchdog that make sure the server stays up. Before, I tried this package on my Ubuntu 10.04 server but it didn't work (many error messages). But for Ubuntu 14.04 on Digital Ocean, it worked perfectly. Thanks!